# Extracting dates from a Microsoft Excel file when dates are in many different formats

Tags: excel

I have been given an excel file with dates in a column for about 17000 rows. The problem here is that the dates are not reliable and the cells have varying formats. Some are formatted as plain text, some are in the "general" format, yet others are in one of several available date formats. In one case, I even found a date in a cell formatted as mm/dd/yyyy yet the date is showing up as 20/05/1989.

The only thing consistent about the dates is that they are actually date-first and month-second to the human reader, irrespective of whatever the format of the cell is. Another things is that the date separator isn't consistently used, some dates have the hyphen, some have the slash and yet others use the dot as the separator.

I intend to add another column next to the column with the dates, and have this column formatted as pure text. Now if I use the formula =TEXT() then this would of course give me the serial (excel) date.

Is there a way to get these dates as text, using VBA if necessary?

Comment: I accepted chuff's answer and it works, except that Excel isn't consistent during importing the data back. The inconsistencies result when the data width varies - I couldn't find a pattern though. So I took chuff's idea and simplified it further - I copied the column to notepad, and then copied it again from notepad to notepad++ (because I'm anal retentive), then copied it back into excel from notepad++ in a new column formatted as pure text. So now I have all the dates as text for further processing. (Final goal is to take these dates to MySQL as proper dates, which is easy if you have text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get a text version of what is displayed in the Excel sheet. Easy way to do this is save the sheet (or just the column in another sheet) as a Formatted Text (Space delimited)(*.prn) file. When you reopen the file, it will be treated as an importable text file.

Comment: I didn't mention earlier, but there are other data columns also. But that's a great tip, thanks.

Comment: Thought it might, that's why I suggested isolating the column in a separate sheet before doing the prn trick. Other than that, I'm a bit stumped, though I'll think about a VBA solution.

Comment: Added a VBA function you can try, @chefsmart.

Comment: Hey, you know what, that *.prn trick is just too good and too simple. I'm gonna mark yours as the accepted answer for that *.prn tip.

Comment: I think you could edit out the VBA and the formula lest others mistake those for the correct answer when really I went with your first suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this formula across and advice.

```
=DAY(A1)&"-"&MONTH(A1)&"-"&YEAR(A1)
```

Regards
Shiva

Comment: Thanks, but it changes the dates where the format doesn't match the date shown. The dates are really day-first, month-second even though the cell may be formatted as mm/dd/yyyy. Also, some cells are not dates at all, they are formatted as text.

Comment: no no it doesnt have you checked it. Please check it and advice.

Comment: I have checked. And unfortunately, some cells are not formatted as dates at all, they are plain text cells.

Comment: can u try doing a format cell option on that column